# oDataModel.read() variable visibility : SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest, sapui5

I have one **oDataModel** and I am reading a particular property, with **read** function. When data read is **success** I am assigning it to a variable. But it is always saying **undefined**

```
readData : function(){
    var oModel = this.getView().getModel();
    var locationID;
    oModel.read('/Locations',{
       success: function(oData,oResponse){
          console.log(oData.results[0].id); //This is printing the data in console, properly
          locationID = oData.results[0].id;
       }
    });
    console.log(locationID); //This is printing as undefined
}
```

Comment: See also [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Answer (score 0):

`read` is asynchronous. When you do `oModel.read`, it essentially fires the request but doesn't block the executing thread. If you do a debug of the above code, you'll observe that execution goes to `console.log(locationID);` immediately after `oModel.read`. At this point, `locationID` is `undefined` (Since assignment hasn't happened yet). The assignment only happens after the callback function `success` is executed.

To solve this, you can wrap your `oModel.read` within a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). You need to resolve your promise inside success.

```js
readData: function() {
    var oModel = this.getView().getModel();
    var locationID;
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        oModel.read('/Locations', {
            success: function (oData, oResponse) {
                console.log(oData.results[0].id);
                locationID = oData.results[0].id;
                resolve(locationID)
            },
            failure: function (oError) {
                reject(oError)
            }
        });
    }).then(data => console.log(data))
}
```

I'm not 100% sure of the syntax, but this should help put you on the right path.